# How do I run an email alert when a specific piece of code is run?

Tags: 14.04, email

I am looking to set up an email alert every time the dirty cow exploit is run as a type of alarm or trigger that is set off every time the code is run, but I have no idea how. I am running it on Ubuntu 14.04 as it is a vulnerable system to the attack.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are referring to the Dirty COW (CVE-2016-5195) privilege escalation vulnerability in the Linux Kernel, then per https://dirtycow.ninja/:

> #### Can I detect if someone has exploited this against me?
>
> Exploitation of this bug does not leave any trace of anything abnormal happening to the logs.

Therefore, there is no clear way to detect if the code has been executed on your system.

---

However, if you're *really* that concerned, you should be aware that the Ubuntu Security Team has already provided a patch for DirtyCOW in the standard linux kernels in Trusty, so if you simply do a standard `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` and upgrade the Linux packages on your system, you'll be patched against this vulnerability.

Comment: If im not mistaken remote exploit goes via httpd or apache, so cant we log attempts like that ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy You'd need a customized plugin in Apache that would be able to pick up specific remote exploit code.  That said, it'd be better to just run an IDS/IPS like Snort with the rulesets for that loaded into it to deny access and protect, AND issue the alerts, than try and set it up themselves.  However, OP doesn't indicate *how* they would be vulnerable to the attack.  Also, if they simply update their server with the repos to the latest kernel in the repos, they get patched for Dirty COW quickly (https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2016/CVE-2016-5195.html).